# Getting photo dimension of locally stored photo

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I'd like to know photos width and height before loading a bitmap. I'm using latest approach of ContentResolver to query locally stored photos.

```
        contentResolver.query(
            collection,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
        )!!.use { cursor ->
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Use an ID column from the projection to get
                // a URI representing the media item itself.
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                val widthColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)

                val id: Long = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val width: Int = cursor.getInt(widthColumn) //CRASH                    
            }
```

Cursor is crashing on the selected line width:

```
IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

How am I supposed to do that then?

Comment: It looks like the column index for the width is wrong as it gives you -1 which is not normal: "col -1 from CursorWindow". Could you double check if this is right ?

Comment: Indeed, it will be -1. So check first then use. But... we cannot see which projection you asked for.. And if you did not ask for it it will certainly be -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT
        )

        val images: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        contentResolver.query(
            images,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )!!.use { cursor ->
            if (cursor.count > 0) {
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                val widthColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH)
                val heightColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT)

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val id: Long = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    val width: Int = cursor.getInt(widthColumn)
                    val height: Int = cursor.getInt(heightColumn)
                    Log.e("tag", " width :: $width - height :: $height");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Stupid mistake of mine. I forgot to add `MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,` in projection